# Ways to tone my stomach area up?

Tags: weight-loss, exercise, abdominals, toning

In the last six months I've lost around 34/35kg. Though I'm skeptical myself a lot of people have told me that I've lost a lot of weight and they can see it. My initial goal was to get to 75kg and reassess my options there. However I'm now considering starting exercises to tone up my stomach area as of the start of next month (**the time I usually add a new exercise to my regime)** and was looking for advice on how I go about doing this.

I'll list my current exercise regime in case it can assist at all/for general feedback on what people think of it.

- **Walking** around 5 kilometers a day (Can vary)
- **Running** 300 meters three days a week (Varies now since I run a bit more)
- **Running** 700/800 meters two days a week (Also varies, did three up until this week)
- **Kettlebell swings** (6 days a week, 3 sets, 10 reps, 16kg) (Did this in an attempt to improve my back, I was in a car accident and it got pretty messed up two years ago and was a source of a lot of pain so I wanted to work on it and fix that, looked into it when I started as even the little running I was doing was resulting in my back hurting a lot, has gotten better as times progressed though)
- **Leg curls** (6 days, 3 sets, 10 reps, 40kg) (Started doing these this month. I decided to try these to see if I could tone my legs up a bit and make them stronger. Initially when I started this exercise regime at the beginning of the new year and I was doing a little bit of running and my legs and ankles were in agony. Though this had improved drastically in the months since I thought adding leg curls might be helpful as I am determined to increase my running distances over time)
- **Continuous running** (Saturdays) (Did 1km Saturday, would've had 2 or so small breaks looking at my distance, weak as I know. I was aiming to do 2 kilometers when I started but unfortunately I just caved in too easily. I'll build up to 2 kilometers and reassess when I get there)

I do a rest day on Friday so I'm going six days a week normally. If I'm really busy or the weathers really bad I'll sometimes not do a full six day week.

It's also probably important to add that I've been dieting and still am. At times you could also most likely say that my dieting had been very aggressive.

Current diet:

**Breakfast:** One yohurt, around 90 calories and low fat, flavors and exact calories vary

**Lunch:** Salad sandwich, sometimes there's also chicken in it maybe once a week

**Dinner:** Salad alongside a main meal containing some kind of meat (Varies, use to just be salad normally until I started my leg curls)

**Drinks:** Water, two coffees a day (completely cut out sugar with my coffee now), green tea with lunch and half a cup of milk after I exercise (No alcohol now unless I'm out with friends)

(If I'm out with friends the diet can fluctuate, coffee count can also if it's during the day. Never see them anymore though so it's hardly relevant unfortunately)

**Additional info:**

- 6ft tall
- Started at 117kg
- Around 83kg now, just went into the healthy weight range BMI category
- Gained a lot of the weight in 20 months but not all

Any advice or feedback is gratefully appreciated. If you need any additional advice please let me know.

Comment: Nope when I came across this website two or three days ago it was the first time I've ever came across it. Sorry I haven't replied to anyones comments so far, taking time to read deeply into the advice you've all offered and research deeper. I was planning on making my final decision on Friday when I have my rest day. I really appreciate the advice you and user 3564421 have given though and I'll likely ask more questions in the next day.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, congratulations on your weight loss, that is really good what you have achieved and you should be proud! First step is always the hardest.

**Diet**

Your diet is pretty good, maybe add in a bit more protein like chicken breast and other lean meat. Potentially when your workouts get a bit more aggressive, you might need to add in a little bit more carbohydrates to give you energy,

**Working on your core**

Now, if you want to work or tone up your stomach area, I would suggest beginning to work on your core as well as your cardio.

Please follow this link here: http://greatist.com/move/best-bodyweight-exercises-abs

This details different exercises you can try out from your own home and so you can try at your own leisure (I usually throw in core workouts at the end of my regular workout).

Just from home, my favourites are the "Bicycle kicks", "Flutter kicks", "Reverse Crunches", "Leg Raises", "Russian Twists" and planking. After a 3 or 4 weeks you can see results if you work the core once every couple days, and depending on your body fat percentage. I usually do 30 seconds worth with 30 seconds rest per exercise (3 or 4 sets). You can up the difficulty when you begin feeling more comfortable.

However, everyone is different, so just experiment with the different types of ab exercises and see what suits you :)

I would also recommend using Youtube to find different types of ab workouts when you feel confident :)

**Potential lifestyle changes**

Also have you considered going to workout at the gym? Different free weight exercises and exercises that target specific areas like bench press (chest), squats(legs), or even shoulder press (shoulder) all work the core as a secondary muscle as well (granted not as much as the target muscle). If not, maybe its time to start incorporating a strength workout into your routine? Start with pushups and see how you feel after that?

Lastly, you could take up a team sport. Nothing helps to motivate me than knowing i'm part of a team! I'm pretty rubbish at most sports but when people see how badly you want to win, and how much effort you put in, they're really inclined to help you to do well and continue on with the sport! For me, it is basketball and football, and both are quite cardio heavy.

**Other misc advice**

Furthermore, can you measure you body fat percentage? It might not be accurate, but could be a decent indicator as to what we are working with. You could google what a 10% body fat percentage person looks like, and a 20% body fat percentage looks like, just to see how you rank with your own bf% percentage.

If you feel like you have too much skin so your abs cannot show, you may need to consult a doctor to see what you can do. They may also be able to calculate your body fat percentage.

Additionally may I ask how old you are?

Any other queries please feel free to ask me!

Comment: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29596/effect-on-abs-leg-raises-vs-crunches/29600#29600 have a look here at some of the ab exercises recommended. Doing floor crunches has been well debunked as a ineffective exercise. Great answer apart from that.

Comment: @JJosaur i don't like crunches, except the reverse crunch which they say is alright from the link you showed xD

Comment: Firstly thank you for the congratulations and well wishes. I struggle to see the results and positives at times given everything but I really appreciate everyone's support.

Comment: How would you suggest I add in chicken or other lean meats? I eat three main meals at the moment so should I incorporate it with one of those or eat before/after exercising? In what form of food should I add carbs and when should I aim to add them to give me maximum energy?

Comment: @AndreDrummondFan

okay from your diet, i'll add suggestions:
Breakfast: One yohurt, around 90 calories and low fat, flavors and exact calories vary + brown bread toast (one or 2 slices)

Lunch: Salad sandwich, sometimes there's also chicken in it maybe once a week + chicken breast/fish/seafood/turkey breast/lean red meat

Dinner: Salad alongside a main meal containing some kind of meat (Varies, use to just be salad normally until I started my leg curls) + definitely have meat (same suggestions as before) and possibly some wholemeal bread or brown rice

trim fats/skin off if you can.

Comment: There's quite a lot of exercises on that list you offered me. What course of action would you suggest I take? How many should I take up for it to be effective? Should I follow what you do yourself, the 12 minute list GreatIst provided or experiment on my own? Sorry for all the questions haha, don't want to do anything wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure where I stand currently on gym membership. At the moment I currently want to join a gym when I can independently pursue it myself, pay for the membership myself and have my licence so I can drive myself to and from the gym, unless my living circumstances change and I can easily get to a gym. I could probably buy a piece of equipment for some strength training as long as it isn't highly priced. Would pursuing push ups be a good choice? Back in high school I was such a scrawny mess when it came to doing push ups haha.

Comment: @AndreDrummondFan what I do at the moment is, Breakfast: 3x nutella toast. || Snack: banana. Lunch: 250g chicken (approx 60g protein content) with bread or 200g chicken + small seafood serving. || Pre-gym snack: Banana/Grapes. || Dinner: Rice (1 to 1.5 cups) and meat dish (approx 150g + meat) + veggies || Drink: Water (throughout day, no coffee) and occasionally Orange/Apple Juice

Comment: I really was wanting to take up a sport again but I'm not sure where I'd go. Around where I'm from the options aren't abundantly massive. We've got cricket in the summer and Australian Rules Football in the winter. I did play cricket manyyyyy years ago but I'm not sure if I'd go back or not and I'm not really to big on Footy.

Comment: @AndreDrummondFan from the ab workout, you could try my favourites and see how you feel: Bicycle kicks", "Flutter kicks", "Reverse Crunches", "Leg Raises", "Russian Twists" (3 sets of 20 seconds, 30 seconds rest inbetween sets, 1 minute inbetween different exercises). Try all of them consecutively until you feel tired, some find abs recover quicker. || Also, dude I was the smallest, skinniest, unathletic guy in high school, couldn't retain weight and had no abs/muscle :( now i get quoted as the fastest they've seen live, well toned and bigger but still short ;D. Trust me, if I can, you can :)

Comment: I'm not to sure on the body fat percentage thing, after 20% the results on Google images get a bit broad to accurately reflect on. I also never took those pesky before and now photos so I'm not one hundred percent sure on how much difference there is since I look at myself everyday hating what I see haha. My BMI's like 24 now though if that helps, it'd definitely probably be somewhere between twenty and mid twenties though. I am 19 years old.

Comment: @AndreDrummondFan Begin by doing pushups yep, but really if you're in the gym, you will get more done and feel a sense of acomplishment afterwards! http://www.builtlean.com/2011/03/02/push-up-variations-exercise/ (I can only do half of these so don't worry if they look so crazy haha)

Comment: @AndreDrummondFan I would definitely recommend hitting a gym, do you have anyone to go with? By following the diet above (or similar), and adding 3 times a week at the gym with a buddy, you will definitely get somewhere. I struggle to bulk and I wish I had more weight so I can convert it into muscle, as opposed to forcing food down to gain weight :(

Comment: @AndreDrummondFan some machines can work it out for you, usually at leisure centres or gyms, they look like big electronic weight machines u stand on but measure height as well.

Comment: @AndreDrummondFan Also, i'm 23, I started at 19 when i was in college, so you definitely can :) feel free to private message me also if you want

Comment: I need to increase my reputation to private PM you, not to sure how to do that haha.

Comment: @AndreDrummondFan Ahh right, ask more good questions or try and answer some on other sites too! i think stay where you are, try and join a gym, persuade your parents to let you join up (if you're still at home), its better than smoking or drugs I guess haha. my family didn't let me join, but when I joined whilst I lived away in college, they instantly changed their mind when they saw the results after 1 year. confidence up, standing straight, acne clearing, more focused and less stressed apparently xD

Comment: Sigh I've spent the entire day reading over and over and pondering what to do. I'm so lost haha.

Comment: @AndreDrummondFan The way i see it:
Add more lean meat to your diet, sustain the salad and possibly add brown bread in the morning.
Start doing pushups, ab workouts. If you can, join a gym.
Do something! It's better than nothing :)

Comment: I calculated my BF percentage and it's between 25 - 26%, pretty disgusting and disappointing considering I'm like 78kg now haha.

Comment: Will doing ab workouts be useful at the moment or does it have to go down more?

Comment: @AndreDrummondFan do ab workouts, cardio, bit of weight lifting. it's finding a balance between them :) if its 25 now, think of how it was before right? Keep going, in small amounts of time it can change by loads of percentages.

Answer (score 0):

### Ways to tone my stomach area up?

First, read the top answer here: [What exercises should I perform to reduce fat on a specific area of my body?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/best-exercise-to-lose-belly-fat-fast)

That said, you do need muscles there and will need to work out. The optimal exercises for building muscle your core muscles are:

- Ab Wheel (kneeling or standing)
- Hanging Leg Raises
- Kneeling Cable Lift
- Exercise Ball (weighted) Crunch
- Turkish Get-ups
- Plank

Make a circuit out of some or all of them. They are in order of importance/effectiveness. However, you could adjust your weights routine to mean you don't need to do many isolation exercises like above (more info below)

### General Feedback on Routine

- Walking/Running: Try to incorporate interval training, walk for 500m then jog for 200m and then repeat. Shorten the walks and lengthen the jogs over time until you are comfortable with jogging/running for 5k. Check out the Couch-to-5k program.
- Weights: Kettlebell exercises are fine and leg curl is a ok assistance exercise but if you really want progression and to build strength then check out the Stronglifts (5x5) Program (and ditch the leg curls). As a minimum you should do: Barbell Squat, Deadlift, Bench Press. Squat and Deadlift (and Overhead Press) all work out your core as it is used to stabilize during the lifts. Alternatively, join a crossfit/body-pump/kettlebell class at your gym and go twice a week. *If you a program designed just for you ask in the comments here and I'll draw one up.*
- Diet: Overall looks good for losing weight but I would be concerned that it is not sustainable, track the calories and macronutrient value of your daily meals and ensure you are getting what you need. IIFYM.com can help tell you your needs and myfitnesspal.com (and app) can help you track.

Comment: I'll comment further in the next few hours but I decided in the last two days to take up your suggestion of interval training for my walking/running and so far I think it's being quite a good suggestion. I really need to take it to the next level in regards to my running and I think that's a good way of doing it so thanks a heap for that suggestion!

Comment: Excellent news, I would advise you set a goal and train towards it, weather its a half/full marathon, cross-country, tough mudder, etc. Having a goal that isn't about aesthetic or weight can be very useful.

Comment: You believe that I'd be best to split my meals into five groups? Should I incorporate some of User's dietary advice and put some protein and carb group foods into two new slots during the day?

Comment: For example: Breakfast > Carb/Protein > Lunch > Carb/Protein > Dinner

Comment: That's not what I am implying. Eat up to your calorie goal for the day and not over, when planning meals look at the macronutrient content. Aim for 1g per lb bodyweight protein, 0.45g per lb of fat and rest as carbs over a day.

Comment: So as I mentioned in the answer by user I'm not to sure whether I can pursue a gym membership or not at the moment so please take that in mind. It looks like four of the six exercises you recommended can be done without a gym membership (excludes hanging leg raises and kneeling cable lifts).

Comment: Do you do Turkish Push-ups yourself? They look like they'd be difficult for a beginner to take up and do perfectly. If I was to do Turkish Get Ups, Ab Wheels, planks and the weighted exercise ball crunches do you believe I'd get good results?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing the kettle bell swings right at the moment. I'll probably have to rewatch some YouTube videos and work on them. Do you think leg curls are ineffective? Most of the other things are pretty gym oriented so I don't know if I can pursue them at the moment :/

Comment: Oh I'm also very much considering downloading the MyFitnessPal app. Looked a few things up on the website that I thought you wouldn't find in a million years (living in Australia and considering they're from a small chicken shop) and was shocked to actually find their calorie values and marconutrient values.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to end up being as thin as a chopstick I would suggest that you **don't drop below 80kg** as this is pretty much around the ideal weight for someone standing 6 feet tall.

To tone your stomach area I believe it's best to **stick with HIIT** ([High Intensity Interval Training](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/wotw40.htm)) from the training perspective and [Intermittent Fasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermittent_fasting) for your diet.

Read more about the effectiveness of the combination of the two [here](http://fitness.mercola.com/sites/fitness/archive/2014/09/26/intermittent-fasting-hiit-workout.aspx).

If you follow **a HIIT training schedule combined with Intermittent Fasting** for about a month, training twice a week, you will be able to shed 3-5kg of fat from your body and allow your abs to start showing themselves.

If you add up a day or two (depending on how much free time you have) to train your abs and strengthen them, at the end of the month you will have some very promising results.

**Some effective ab exercises**:

1. V-Crunches
2. Russian Twists
3. Plank
4. Oblique Driving-Knee Crunches
5. V-hold

**Diet**:

You already do a decent job with your diet keeping the sugar intake at a minimum, but you should consider increasing the protein intake throughout the day and also, get a good dose carbohydrates after your training to replace the lost energy.